# Проблема с функцией добавления данных в программе подключеной к БД C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных

SqlException: Конфликт инструкции INSERT с ограничением FOREIGN KEY "FK_User_Role". Конфликт произошел в базе данных "TestBase", таблица "dbo.Role", column 'ID'.
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public NewUserPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CmbRole.ItemsSource = AppData.db.Role.ToList();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User people = new User();

        people.Login = LoginTxb.Text;
        people.Password = Password_Txb.Text;

        var CurrentRole = CmbRole.SelectedItem as Role;
        people.RoleID = CurrentRole.ID;

        AppData.db.User.Add(people);
        AppData.db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Пользователь был добавлен  в базу");
        NavigationService.GoBack();

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145236/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.